# CSS class not changing font color

Tags: html, css, colors

I have this code that I am working on in CSS. For some reason the class will not change the color of the paragraph and I am unsure as to why.

```
<div id="formsHead">
    <div id="loginT" class="active">
        <p id="loginL">Login</p>
    </div>
    <div id="registerT" class="active">
        <p id="registerR">Register</p>
    </div>
</div>

#loginT{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
}
#registerT{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
}
.active{
    background:#ecf0f1;
}
.active p{
        color:#34495e;
}
```

Here is a jsFiddle of the full code:

http://jsfiddle.net/nvmzygqg/

Comment: Seems to be working on my end. http://jsfiddle.net/e7t1mnjy/

Comment: The color is changing: http://jsfiddle.net/sfexvhf7/. It's a dark color maybe that's why you're unable to notice it.

Comment: Does not seem to work my end, would you like to see a full js fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector needs to be more specific. In your example it's being overriden by the `#formsHead p` selector. Adding the ID of each parent in your example will do the trick:

```
#loginT.active p,
#registerT.active p {
    color: #34495e;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing something like this:

```
p.active{
background:#ecf0f1;
color:#34495e;
}
```

This will apply class to all paragraphs by default.

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
.active:active{background-color:blue;}
```

or is it maybe focusing you want?

```
.active:focus{background-color:red;}
```

Comment: I have added the full code on js as I feel it may be something else causing it.

Comment: you want it to change on focus, right? 2nd of my code, instead of background you can change borders,outlines etc,etc

Comment: I'm not chaining it on focus, I just want the class to work on it. I am adding and removing the class using javascript, havnt coded that yet.

Comment: according to your js fiddle code it's the text in `#userL{color:#34495e;}`.

Comment: if it's the text in the input box that you want to color than change `.active p` to `#userL` in your css

Comment: is it like this you want it? I changed it to red to make it stand out [JS FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/nvmzygqg/)

Comment: Sorry no it doesn't, also does not further my question.